# unable to get array length of object property in javascript

Tags: javascript

defined a simple javascript object and assigned array to one property but not able to get the length of the array. returning 2 rather than 1 for below code.

```
//activity object
var activity={
    timer:0,
    questions_completed:new Array(2),
    knifes:0,
    getTimer:function(){
        return timer; 
    } 
};

alert(activity.questions_completed.length); //getting 2?
```

Comment: `new Array(2)` means create an array of length 2. Why do you expect 1?

Comment: seems legit, what's the issue?

Comment: javascript arrays are 0 based, so if you define an Array(2) that means an array with a length of 2 and a max index of 1 (starting at 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new Array` with a **single** parameters passed to it as number, will create an array with specific length:

```
var arr = new Array(2);

arr;
// -> [undefined, undefined]

arr.length;
// -> 2
```

Instead use `[]` notation:

```
var arr = [2];

arr;
// -> [2]

arr.length;
// -> 1
```

---

```
var activity = {
    timer:0,
    questions_completed: [2],
    knifes:0,
    getTimer:function(){
        return timer; 
    } 
};

alert(activity.questions_completed.length);
// 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line defines the length of your array which is 2, however you have not pushed any item in your array the length will show 2, which is absolutely correct..!

questions_completed:new Array(2)